# Is there a way to rerun OnInitializedAsync when a variable is changed in Blazor WASM?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I understand OnInitializedAsync is running once before the component is loaded. However, I am passing in a variable to the API and I would like to have it rerender the UI once the variable is changed. I am just not sure what the best way to go about it is.

```
@page "/"
@inject HttpClient Http

<h1>Pokemon</h1>

<p></p>

@if (pokemons == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
            @foreach (var n in pokemons.results)
                {
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img src=@n.url class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">@n.name</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }


    @pokemons.count
    <br />

    @offset
    <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
        <ul class="pagination">
            @for (int b = 0; b < pokemons.count; b += 20)
            {
                int local_b = b;
                <li class="page-item"><button class="page-link" @onclick="() => Paginate(local_b)">@b</button></li>
            }
        </ul>
    </nav>
}

@code {
    private PokemonList pokemons;
    private PokemonDetail pokemonDetails;
    private int limit = 20;
    private int offset = 0;

    public void Paginate(int value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
        this.offset = value;
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        pokemons = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<PokemonList>($"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?offset={offset}&limit={limit}");

        foreach (var p in pokemons.results)
        {
            pokemonDetails = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<PokemonDetail>(p.url);

            p.url = pokemonDetails.sprites.front_default;
        }
    }

    public class PokemonList
    {
        public int count { get; set; }
        public string next { get; set; }
        public List<Pokemon> results { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pokemon
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }

    public class PokemonDetail
    {
        public PokemonSprites sprites { get; set; }
    }

    public class PokemonSprites
    {
        public string front_default { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean re-render when the state has changed?

Comment: I think you are mixing concepts. `OnInitializedAsync` runs once when the page is first loaded, but that does not render the page. If you need to re-render the page use `StateHasChanged();`, else if what you want is to run the code you have inside `OnInitializedAsync` then put it in an external function and call it from `OnInitializedAsync`  and from where you assing the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a function for your API call and can call this function whenever you want

```
  private async Task FetchPokemonList()
  {
        pokemons = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<PokemonList>($"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?offset={offset}&limit={limit}");

        foreach (var p in pokemons.results)
        {
            pokemonDetails = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<PokemonDetail>(p.url);

            p.url = pokemonDetails.sprites.front_default;
        }
  }
```

And can call FetchPokemonList in OnInitializedAsync

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
   await FetchPokemonList();
}
```

Comment: To add to that, look into the OnParametersSet event. For even deeper and more complex things, also OnSetParameters